# Cayley graph attempt

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried modifying the latex code from a previous Cayley graph post on this site, but the arrows are not connecting correctly. The image looks ok for the first five nodes, then it falls apart. I'm trying to produce an image like the one attached below. Sorry for the multiple accounts, I connected my email to the account, so I don't have to post as a guest anymore and I can answer comments, which I wasn't able to do in my previous post. I've provided a minimum working example, and any feedback will help.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mid arrow/.style={postaction={
  decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Triangle}}},
  decorate}},looseness=0.5]

\foreach \i [count=\j, count=\r from 0] in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}{
   \node (r\j) at (90+36-\j*36:3/2) {$\ifnum\i=1e\else r_\r\fi$};
}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i, 5)+1);}] in {1,...,10}{
  \draw [blue, mid arrow] (r\i) to [bend left] node [auto] {$r_1$} (r\j);
  \draw [purple, mid arrow] (r\j) to [bend left] node [auto] {$r_1$} (r\i);
} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by your drawing – would you be able to clean it up a bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this? But if you have several of these to draw, you are going to need to sit down with the TikZ manual sooner or later and read the bits relevant to your needs.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    mid arrow/.style={%
      postaction={%
        decoration={%
          markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Triangle}},
        },
        decorate,
      },
    },
    my label/.style={%
      auto, midway, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1.5pt
    },
    looseness=0.5
  ]
  \colorlet{my colour}{black}%
  \foreach \i [count=\j, count=\r from 0, evaluate=\j as \k using {90+36-\j*36}] in {1,...,10}{
    \node [circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=2.5pt, label={\k:$\ifnum\i=1e\else r_\r\fi$}] (r\j) at (90+36-\j*36:3/2) {};
  }
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i,10)+1);}] in {1,...,10}{
    \ifodd\j \colorlet{my colour}{blue}\def\tempa{$d_1$}\else \colorlet{my colour}{purple}\def\tempa{$d_2$}\fi
    \draw [my colour, mid arrow] (r\i) to [bend left] node [my label] {\tempa} (r\j);
    \draw [my colour, mid arrow] (r\j) to [bend left] node [my label] {\tempa} (r\i);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: modified Cayley]

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I have one question: I know how to remove the black dots, but how can I move the r labels to those positions. I know I hadn't drawn this in my sketch, so I thank you for being so exact.

Comment: Just use the method which Mark Wibrow used in answering your other question. I only changed it to match what you'd drawn: I assumed that was part of the modification you were trying to achieve. That is, just put the r or whatever in the node and drop the `label`.